# How to display errors that are not related to validating form fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

If I would need to display errors related to form fields, I would use the tag helpers in View:

```
<span asp-validation-for="SomeField"></span>
```

and either use data validation attributes in the model class or call

```
ModelState.AddModelError("SomeField", "Error message");
```

in controller.

Now I need to display an error message in the Login page if login fails. Something general like "Invalid login attempt." Is there an inbuilt mechanism for that?

Adding a new unused property in a model so I can use "asp-validation-for" tag helper and AddModelError feels wrong. Should I use ViewBag or ViewData or is another way?

Answer (score 1):

Just found how to do it.

Add a new div using asp-validation-summary tag helper in the view.

```
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-warning"></div>
```

And in controller action generate an error using an empty string:

```
ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt");
```